# How to update another cell value when "vlookup" value is updated?

Tags: excel

I have two files: 'First' and 'Second'.
When cell 'B1' in file 'First' is updated from "vlookup" function from file 'Second', I want to show it in file 'First'.

I want smth like this: "If 'B1' is changed, set 'A1' to "changed"
Then I want to delete "changed", and again, if value 'B1' is changed, I want "changed" appear into cell A1.

Comment: Setup up a WorkSheet_Change event handler. Search here for examples.

Comment: You can copy the column containing the vlookup formula and paste it as values besides it, when you feel any change has happened you can compare both columns.